# How dynamic in wp shortcode

Tags: wordpress

How dynamic in wp shortcode data-filter-class='["london", "art"]?

```
<ol id="filters">
  <li data-filter="amsterdam">Amsterdam</li>

</ol>
<br/>

<div id="main" role="main">

  <ul id="tiles">

    <li data-filter-class='["london", "art"]'>
      <img src="../sample-images/image_1.jpg" height="283" width="200">
      <p>London Art</p>
    </li>
    <!-- End of grid blocks -->
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add more details to your question? Right now, it is absolutely unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to dynamic date from this two <li data-filter="amsterdam">Amsterdam</li> and <li data-filter-class='["london", "art"]'> filter data for wp shortcode function.

Comment: 1. Please update the post itself with the new information, instead of adding comments, that is more likely to attract readers. 2. I think that your question would greatly benefit from adding some *(main) verbs*.